# Form's embedded jQuery Validate link creates an issue sending email, but if creates other issues if moved within file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I am using a form that is validated with jQuery Validate and general validation.

Currently, I am having two issues:

The hierarchy of my files that have been embedded on my page are as follows:

- (1) PHP
- (2) jquery-1.11.3.js
- (3) jquery.validate.js
- (4) jQuery Validation Scripts

***Issue (A)*** is that although the fields are correctly validated and the 'red' class is added to all incorrect input fields, the email sends but the success message doesn't appear.

If I change the hierarchy of the embedded files to:

- (1) PHP
- (2) jquery-1.11.3.js
- (4) jQuery Validation Scripts
- (3) jquery.validate.js

***Issue (B)*** I get is that although the fields are correctly validated, the 'red' class no longer gets added to any of the input fields. Also, the success message now appears but the form sends an email that has no inputted data.

How do I get around these issues so that the form works the way it should (in Issue A) but sends an email with the data in its message?

So to clarify, I want the form to work the way it is in Issue (A), the problem is that the email is being sent blank. But if I change the hierarchy of the embedded files, the email now sends the data but the success message doesn't appear.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div id="after_submit"></div> 
    <form id="contact_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <input id="name" class="input required" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
  </div>

  <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <input id="email" class="input required" name="email" type="email" value="" size="30"/><br />
  </div>

  <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <input id="telephone" class="input" name="telephone" type='tel'><br />
  </div>

  <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <input id="event_date" class="input required" name="event_date" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
  </div>

  <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <input id="guests" class="input required" name="guests" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
  </div>

  <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <input id="hear_about" class="input required" name="hear_about" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br />
  </div>

  <div id="form-container" class="row form-input-group">
    <textarea id="message" class="input required" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
  </div>

    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$subject = 'Website Contact Form Submission';

$message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["name"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["email"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Telephone:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["telephone"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event Date:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["event_date"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Guests Amount:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["guests"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hear About:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["hear_about"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["message"]."</td></tr>
     </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";                      


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From: ".$_POST["name"]." <".$_POST["email"].">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["name"]." <".$_POST["email"].">\r\n";

mail("example@example.com",$subject,$message,$headers);

$nameErr = $emailErr = $telephoneErr = $hear_aboutErr = $messageErr = "";
$name = $email = $telephone = $event_date = $guests = $hear_about = $message = ""; 

$name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $event_date = $_POST['event_date']; // not required

    $guests = $_POST['guests']; // not required

    $hear_about = $_POST['hear_about']; // required

    $message = $_POST['message']; // required


// required
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

// required
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }  

// not required
   if (empty($_POST["telephone"])) {
     $telephoneErr = "Incorrect telephone format";
   } else {
     $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
     // check if telephone  is well-formed
     if ( preg_match( '/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\(\.\-\s]?([\d]{3})[\)\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/', $string ) ) {
       $telephoneErr = "Invalid telephone format";
     }
   }

// not required
    if (empty($_POST["event_date"])) {
     $event_date = "";
   } else {
     $event_date = test_input($_POST["event_date"]);
   }

// not required
    if (empty($_POST["guests"])) {
     $guests = "";
   } else {
     $guests = test_input($_POST["guests"]);
   } 

// required
    if (empty($_POST["hear_about"]) < 5) {
     $hear_aboutErr = "Please let us know where you heard about us";
   } else {
     $hear_about = test_input($_POST["hear_about"]);
   }

// required
   if (empty($_POST["message"]) < 5) {
     $messageErr = "Not enough characters";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }
}  

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

    }
?>
```

**OTHER JQUERY VALIDATIONS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    debug: true,

    $("#contact_form").validate({

        rules: {

            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                letters : true,
            },

            email: {
                email: true,
            },

            telephone: {
                required: false,
                digits: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },

            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
            }

        },

       messages: {

            name: {
                required: "Please enter a name",
                minlength: "Name is not long enough",
                letters: "Please enter characters only"
            },

            email: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },

            message: {
                required: "Please enter a message",
                minlength: "Please enter at least 5 characters"
            },

            telephone: {
                digits: "Please enter a valid phone number",
                minlength: "Phone number is not long enough"
            }

            },

        errorElement : 'span',
        errorClass:'error',
        validClass:'success',

            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).parents("#form-container").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); 

            }, 
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
            $(element).parents("#form-container").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); 
        },
    });


    var errors = false;

    $('.required').parent().find('.input').on('blur', function() {
        var field_container = $(this).parent();
        if (!$.empty_field_validation($(this).val())) {
            errors = true;

        } else {
            field_container.removeClass('error');
            errors = false;
        }

    });

    $('#name').on('blur', function(){
        var field_container = $(this).parent();
        if (!$.empty_field_validation($(this).val())) {

        $("#name").addClass("red");
            errors = true;

        } else {
            $("#name").removeClass("red");
                errors = false;
        }

    });

    $('#message').on('blur', function(){
        var field_container = $(this).parent();
        if (!$.empty_field_validation($(this).val())) {

        $("#message").addClass("red");
            errors = true;

        } else {

            $("#message").removeClass("red");
                errors = false;
        }

    });

    $('#email').on('blur', function(){
        var field_container = $(this).parent();
        if (!$.email_validation($(this).val())) {

        $("#email").addClass("red");
            errors = true;

        } else {

            $("#email").removeClass("red");
                errors = false;
        }

    });

    $('#telephone').on('blur', function(){
        var field_container = $(this).parent();
        if (!$.tel_validation($(this).val())) {

        $("#telephone").addClass("red");
            errors = true;

        } else {

            $("#telephone").removeClass("red");
                errors = false;
        }

    });

    $('#contact_form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         $('.required').parent().find('.input').trigger('blur');

        if (!errors)
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject())
                },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data) {
                    var message = 'Hi '+data.name+'. Your message was sent and received.';
                    $('#after_submit').html(message);
                    $('#after_submit').css('display', 'block');
                },
                error: function() {
                    var message = 'Hi '+data.name+'. Your message could not be sent or received. Please try again later';
                    $('#after_submit').html(message);
                    $('#after_submit').css('display', 'block'); 
                }
            });
        });

    });

    $.empty_field_validation = function(field_value) {
        if (field_value.trim() == '') return false;
        return true;
    }

    $.validator.addMethod('letters', function(value) { //Custom Method Validator
        return value.match(/^[- a-zA-Z]+$/);
    });

    $.email_validation = function(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
    }

    $.tel_validation = function(telephone) {
        var regex = /^\d{3}(?: ?\d+)*$/;
        return regex.test(telephone);
    }

    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {

       var o = {};
       var a = this.serializeArray();

       $.each(a, function() {
           if (o[this.name]) {
               if (!o[this.name].push) {
                   o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
               }
               o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
           } else {
               o[this.name] = this.value || '';
           }
       });

    return o;
};
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width: 414px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#after_submit, #email_validation, #name_validation {
    display:none;
}

#after_submit{
    background-color: #c0ffc0;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

label, #after_submit{
    color: #6c6c6c;
}

input{
    line-height: 31px;
}

input, textarea{
    width: 288px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    border: solid 1px #b6c7cb;
}

#contact_form{
    height: 317px;
    background-color: #e1e9eb;
    border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
    padding: 10px 20px 50px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit_button{
    width: 109px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #86c5fa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.29);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.29);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.29);
    border: solid 1px #77a4cb;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

label.required:after {
  content:'*';
  color:#cb2027;
}

.red {
  color: #cb2027;
  border: 1px solid #cb2027;
}

.error_message{
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.row {
  margin:5px;
}

#email-error, #message-error, #name-error, #telephone-error {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    color: #cb2027;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 288px;
}
```